# FB.api only loads on first AJAX call to page

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, sdk

I have an issue with an FB.api only loading the first time a page is retrieved via AJAX. FB.getLoginStatus does work though.

Demo page: http://proof.ptly.com/test/fb/test-ajax.htm (clicking the load link works the first time but fails the second time it is clicked)

**Expected/Desired behaviour**: after giving permission to the app, it should list of all groups or pages associated to the user

**Current behaviour**: group list is only populated on first load. subsequent clicks do not load the list (FB.api does not return a response - view console for logging)

The reason behind this problem is that the page I am retrieving (test.htm) can't be changed but the page I am calling it from (test-ajax.htm) can. While I know this method isn't pretty nor ideal, I'm wondering if it is possible to overcome. Thus suggestions to change the underlying test.htm, while correct, won't solve the problem I'm having.

### Sample code

Main page that calls the AJAX page

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
        var loaded = false;
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery("#lnk").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                jQuery("#divContent").load("test.htm", function(){
                    if(loaded)
                    {

                        FB.getLoginStatus(FBverifyLogin);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        loaded = true;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" id='lnk'>load</a>
        <div id='divContent'></div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

AJAX page being retrieved

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var FB_config = {
            API_ID: "347798778614308",
            PERMISSIONS: "publish_stream,manage_pages,user_groups",
        };
        (function(d){
           var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
           d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
         }(document));


        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            // initialise FB
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                    appId      : '347798778614308',
                    status     : true, 
                    cookie     : true,
                    xfbml      : true,
                    oauth      : true
                });
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', FBverifyLogin);
            };
        });


        function FBverifyLogin(response) {
            console.log("FBverifyLogin");
            console.log(response);
            jQuery("#FBreauth").hide();
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
                // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                // request, and the time the access token 
                // and signed request each expire
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                ShowPostToFacebookCheckbox();
                FBdisplayMyPages(response.authResponse);
                jQuery("#btnLogin").hide();
                checkPermissions();

            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

            } else {
                // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
                jQuery("#btnLogin").show();
                return false;
            }
        }
        function checkPermissions(){
            console.log("checkPermissions");
            FB.api('/me/permissions', function(response) {
                console.log("in checkPermissions fb.api");
                console.log(response);
                var permissions = FB_config.PERMISSIONS.split(",");
                for(var i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                {
                    if(response.data[0][permissions[i]] == undefined || response.data[0][permissions[i]] != 1)
                    {
                        jQuery("#FBreauth").show();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        function FBdisplayMyPages(authResponse){
            console.log("FBdisplayMyPages");
            console.log(authResponse);
            FB.api('/me/accounts', function(response) {
                console.log("in FBdisplayMyPages fb.api");
                console.log(response);
                var str = "";
                var name = "";
                var count = 0;
                str += '<optgroup label="Pages">';
                for(var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++)
                {
                    if(response.data[i].category != "Application")
                    {
                        name = response.data[i].name;
                        str += '<option value="'+response.data[i].id+"_"+response.data[i].access_token+'">'+name+'</option>';
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                str += "</optgroup>";

                jQuery("#msgPostOn").html(str);
                FB.api('/me/groups', function(response) {
                    console.log("in FBdisplayMyPages fb.api 2");
                    console.log(response);

                    str = jQuery("#msgPostOn").html();
                    str += '<optgroup label="Groups">';
                    name = "";

                    for(var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++)
                    {
                        if(response.data[i].category != "Application")
                        {
                            name = response.data[i].name;
                            str += '<option value="'+response.data[i].id+"_"+authResponse.accessToken+'">'+name+'</option>';
                            count++;

                        }
                    }
                    str += "</optgroup>";
                    jQuery("#msgPostOn").html(str);

                    switch(count)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            // notify that there are not pages. will post to personal page
                            str += '<option value="' + authResponse.userID + "_" + authResponse.accessToken + '">Personal Account</option>';
                            jQuery("#msgPostOn").html(str);
                            jQuery("#FBpostTo").text("No pages found. Posting to your personal account");
                            jQuery("#FBpostTo").show();

                            break;
                        case 1:
                            // only 1 page. hide it...
                            // notify name of page to update

                            jQuery("#msgPostOn").hide();
                            jQuery("#FBpostTo").html("Posting to <strong>" + name + "</strong>");
                            jQuery("#FBpostTo").show();
                            break;
                        default:
                            // notify user to select a page to post to
                            jQuery("#FBpostTo").text("There are multiple groups/pages associated with your account. Specify which to post to ");
                            jQuery("#FBpostTo").show();
                            jQuery("#msgPostOn").show();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        function FBrefresh(){
            console.log("FBrefresh");
            FB.getLoginStatus(FBverifyLogin);
        }
        function FBreauth(){
            console.log("FBreauth");
            FB.ui(
                {
                    method: 'oauth',
                    display: 'popup',

                    app_id: FB_config.API_ID,
                    client_id: FB_config.API_ID,
                    redirect_uri: "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html",

                    scope: FB_config.PERMISSIONS
                }
            );          
        }

        function ShowPostToFacebookCheckbox() 
        { 
            console.log("ShowPostToFacebookCheckbox");
            jQuery('#postToFacebook2').css('display', 'inline'); 
            jQuery('#LabelForFacebook').css('display', 'inline'); 
        }

    </script>       

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<div id="postToFacebookField" class="fieldContainer checkbox ">
    <div id="btnLogin" class="fb-login-button" scope="publish_stream,manage_pages,user_groups">Login with Facebook</div>
    <input type="checkbox" style="display:none" name="postToFacebook2" value="on" id="postToFacebook2"> 
    <label style="cursor: pointer; display:none" for="postToFacebook2" id="LabelForFacebook">Post to Facebook Page</label>
    <div id="FBpostTo" style="display: none"></div>
    <select id="msgPostOn" style="display: none"></select>
    <div style="display: none" id="FBreauth">(Insufficient permissions. <a href ='#' onclick='FBreauth(); return false;'>Authorize this app</a> and <a href='#' onclick='FBrefresh() ; return false'>refreshing</a>)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what does happen and what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: Also, I think you are missing the point of ajax.

Comment: The second time you do your AJAX call, the Facebook JavaScript SDK __is__ already loaded in your page – so I guess `window.fbAsyncInit` doesn’t fire again (and I’d say that’s correct behavior).

Comment: @NitzanTomer: While I understand that this isn't 'proper AJAX', I'm just trying to work around an existing system that I can't be modified. But more importantly, I want to understand what exactly is going on and if it is possible to overcome

Comment: @Heinzi: Thanks for the feedback. I've added it to my question

Comment: As @CBroe wrote, there's no need to load/init the SDK more than once. After the first time it was loaded you're good to go.

Comment: @CBroe this is true and was the reason why I added code to run `FB.getLoginStatus(FBverifyLogin)` manually if the page had been loaded before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are still looking for a solution to this problem, I believe I have something that might work within the constraints that you have set. Quite simply, we just clear all the loaded variables and objects in memory, and from my tests, including the `<script>` that facebook attaches.

Replace the click handler in test.htm with this and it should work

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#lnk").click(function(e){
        if(FB && document.getElementById("facebook-jssdk")){ //if set, reset
              //removes the <script>
          document.head.removeChild(document.getElementById("facebook-jssdk")); 
          window.FB=null; //unloads the APIs
          loaded=null; 
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery("#divContent").load("test.htm", function(){
            if(loaded)
            {
                FB.getLoginStatus(FBverifyLogin);
            }
            else
            {   
                loaded = true;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved our day!

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar kind of issue, this post http://www.martincarlin.info/facebook-js-sdk-not-working-on-second-load-of-ajax-loaded-page/ helped us to resolve the issue.

The reason the script was not working was because the window.fbAsyncInit function runs on the initial page load and so the second time you do your AJAX call, the Facebook JavaScript SDK is already loaded in your page so window.fbAsyncInit doesn’t fire again.

By checking if FB is already defined we can then use our SDK code without the initialisation part.

Hope that will help you to resolve the issue.

Comment: The given link does not work any more. Can you please share your peace of code which you did to fix this..

Comment: the link doesnt work. Can you show us how it was solved ?

Answer (score 1):

After trying everything from past few days this below piece of code worked for me.

```
//intialize FB object (this is useful if you are using Turbolinks)
$(document).on('page:load', function(){
 intializeFB();
});

intializeFB();

function intializeFB(){
 if(typeof(FB) !== "undefined"){
  delete FB;
 }
 $.getScript("http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1",      function () {
   FB.init({
     appId      : '19871816653254',
     cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                         // the session
     xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
     oauth      : true,
     status     : true,
     version    : 'v2.4' // use version 2.4
   });
 });
}
```

Hope this is useful!